# How to make a div extend to the bottom of a scrollable page? ASP

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've been trying to get my sidebar to the bottom of the page, I dont want it to be position fixed because then the buttons would do a scroll along and I don't want that. I just want the background to extend to the bottom of the scrollable page. I've tried multiple "Solutions" and the only two outcomes I've had are that the background extends to the bottom of the visible page or just around the buttons... so yeah. I also ont want it to be like height:3000px, because of different screen resolutions.

This is in a Master Page

How it is: http://prntscr.com/7dpa8j

ASP of masterpage:

```
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="mainSM" runat="server" />

        <div id="header">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentHolderDD" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div>
                <p id="teamNames" class="regularTextWhite">Tom, Rutger & Mike</p>
            </div>

            <img id="logo" src="../../Images/top2000.gif" />
            <div>
                <p id="welcomeMessage" class="regularTextWhite" runat="server">Welkom FIRST_NAME</p>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogout" text="Uitloggen" runat="server" CssClass="btnRed"  Visible="false" OnClick="btnLogout_Click"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" text="Inloggen" runat="server" CssClass="btnRed" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />     
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="sideMenu" runat="server">
                <asp:Button ID="btnList" text="Lijst" runat="server" CssClass="btnClean" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/Pages/List.aspx"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnArtists" text="Artiesten" runat="server" CssClass="btnClean" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/Pages/Artists.aspx"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSongs" text="Lietjes" runat="server" CssClass="btnClean" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/Pages/Song.aspx"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
background-color: white;
border-right: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
width: 250px;
height:1000px;
float:left;
overflow-y:auto;
position:relative;

}

#sidemenu {
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: If you change the asp to the relevant / needed html only and prepare a demo (plunkr, pen.io, jsfiddle) it is easier to help and therefore more likely ([good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

SET height : 100vh;

```
#sidebar {
background-color: white;
border-right: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
width: 250px;
height:100vh;
float:left;
overflow-y:auto;
position:relative;

}
```